# Trouble with plot matrix with image and xrange

Tags: matrix, gnuplot

I have trouble with xrange. When I put 'set autoscale xfix' image is ok but information axis not. When i put xrange [-1:1] i get info ok but images is damage. Second trouble is flip image. In my data stored in file upper left corner is -1 on image is +1, why?

my data is:

```
-0.999770 -0.998743  0.946455  0.999678  0.999777 
-0.699447 -0.999784 -0.999565 -0.076214  0.999467 
 0.999921 -0.717181 -0.999790 -0.999734 -0.959481 
 0.999943  0.999920 -0.733798 -0.999793 -0.999786 
 0.999943  0.999943  0.999920 -0.749453 -0.999794
```

my code is:

```
set terminal png transparent enhanced font "arial,10" fontscale 1.0 size 600, 400 
set output 'out.png'
set xtics 0.25
set ytics 0.25

set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [-1:1]
set cbrange [-1:1]

plot 'data.txt' matrix with image
```

[image: test image]

My image is -1 to 1 step 0.5
if I add set xrange [-1:1] and set yrange [-1:1] I get
[image: ugly image]

```
$ gnuplot -V
gnuplot 5.0 patchlevel 3
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the thing is that your data file is interpreted as a uniform `matrix`. In this case:

```
gnuplot> help matrix
 Gnuplot can interpret matrix data input in two different ways.

 The first of these assumes a uniform grid of x and y coordinates and assigns
 each value in the input matrix to one element M[i,j] of this uniform grid.
 The assigned x coordinates are the integers [0:NCOLS-1].
 The assigned y coordinates are the integers [0:NROWS-1].
```

So this means that the datapoints in the first row of your file will have `y`-coordinate set to 0, second row 1, etc. However, since the `y`-axis by default points upwards, the resulting image is therefore flipped. Also, these points define the centers of the elementary color squares/boxes in the plot. So that's way the "effective x/y-range" is in your case `[-0.5:4.5]`.

To "fix" the `y`-axis, you could use

```
set yr [] reverse
```

Here, `[]` specifies that the axis is still autoscaled.

Finally, to rescale your image from [0,4] into the [-1,1] range, you could use:

```
fn(x) = x/2. - 1
plot 'data.txt' matrix u (fn($1)):(fn($2)):3 w image
```

So in total:

```
set terminal png transparent enhanced font "arial,10" fontscale 1.0 size 600, 400
set output 'out.png'
set xtics 0.25
set ytics 0.25

set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [-1:1] reverse
set cbrange [-1:1]

fn(x)=x/2-1
plot 'data.txt' matrix u (fn($1)):(fn($2)):3 w image
```

**EDIT**:

One could also adapt the script above to deal with a matrix of a priori unknown size:

```
set terminal png transparent enhanced font "arial,10" fontscale 1.0 size 600, 400
set output 'out.png'

set xrange [-1:1]
set yrange [-1:1] reverse
set cbrange [-1:1]

fName = 'data.txt'
stats fName nooutput

N = STATS_records - 1

set xtics 1./N
set ytics 1./N

fn(x)=(2*x/N)-1
plot fName matrix u (fn($1)):(fn($2)):3 w image
```

Here, the `stats` command first scans the file and stores the number of records into a special variable `STATS_records`. The function `fn` then rescales the range `[0:STATS_records-1]` on `[-1:1]`. Also, the `x/y-`tics are adapted automatically.

Comment: Is possible to read max range data? sometimes i use more data is possible to write automatic function? Chodzi o to, że jeśli chce z większą rozdzielczością wygenerować obrazem muszę zmieniac funkcję f() a może dało by się to zrobić jakoś automatycznie.

Comment: @EliaszŁukasz I have included an extension for general square matrices. The script first finds out the size of the matrix and then adjusts the scaling as well as the tics.